# Logically index Data based upon two date time arrays in matlab

Tags: matlab, datetime, indexing, logical-operators

I will jump straight into a minimal example as I find this difficult to put into words. I have the following example:

```
Data.Startdate=[datetime(2000,1,1,0,0,0) datetime(2000,1,2,0,0,0) datetime(2000,1,3,0,0,0) datetime(2000,1,4,0,0,0)];
Data.Enddate=[datetime(2000,1,1,24,0,0) datetime(2000,1,2,24,0,0) datetime(2000,1,3,24,0,0) datetime(2000,1,4,24,0,0)];
Data.Value=[0.5 0.1 0.2 0.4];
Event_start=[datetime(2000,1,1,12,20,0) datetime(2000,1,1,16,0,0) datetime(2000,1,4,8,0,0)];
Event_end=[datetime(2000,1,1,14,20,0) datetime(2000,1,1,23,0,0) datetime(2000,1,4,16,0,0)];
```

What I want to do is add a flag to the Data structure (say a 1) if any time between Data.Startdate and Data.Enddate falls between Event_start and Event_end. In the example above Data.Flag would have have the values 1 0 0 1 because from the Event_start and Event_end vectors you can see there are events on January 1st and January 4th. The idea is that I will use this flag to process the data further.

I am sure this is straightforward but would appreciate any help you can give.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would convert the dates to numbers using `datenum`, which then allows fairly convenient comparisons using `bsxfun`:

```
isStartBeforeEvent = bsxfun(@gt,datenum(Event_start)',datenum(Data.Startdate));
isEndAfterEvent = bsxfun(@lt,datenum(Event_end)',datenum(Data.Enddate));

flag = any(isStartBeforeEvent & isEndAfterEvent, 1)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer but what if Event_start and Data.Startdate have different dimensions? Apologies for not clarifying that in my original post.

Comment: @user1912925: As long as both are row vectors, my code should not care (as your example has different numbers of events and dates, I have even been able to test it). The `bsxfun` line compares all starts/ends against one another, creating two nEvents-by-mDates arrays for further processing.

Comment: Strange I am getting the bsxfun error "Non-singleton dimensions of the two input arrays must match each other" (in my "real case" Data.Startdate is 1 x 863 and Event_start is 340 x 1 or 1 x 340 after transposing it as you do in your example). I can see no other difference between my real case and the minimal example above which does indeed work using your solution.

Comment: @user1912925: in your example, both were 1-by-n, which required me to transpose the events. If the events are n-by-1, don't transpose and everything works.